# Shortcut proof by calculation for addition/subtraction, "The Mechanics of Proof", and mathlib4

Tags: lean4, beginner, lean-mathlib

In Macbeth's book 'The Mechanics of Proof,' the author [provides a tactic](https://hrmacbeth.github.io/math2001/01_Proofs_by_Calculation.html#a-shortcut) called `addarith` to eliminate the need to write `calc` proofs for facts that can be derived from addition and subtraction. For example,

```
example {x : ℤ} (h1 : x + 4 = 2) : x = -2 := by addarith [h1]
```

**Is an equivalent already part of mathlib4?  If so, how would I find it?**

(I wasn't able to find it in either the prelude or searching, but I haven't developed enough familiarity and good search patterns yet.)

Comment: There's an appendix to the book which lists the mainstream-Lean equivalents of the custom tactics in the book: https://hrmacbeth.github.io/math2001/Mainstream_Lean.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is such at tactic, it is called `linarith`, the following statement works for me using `leanprover/lean4:v4.4.0-rc1` (but it will probably work with much older versions of mathlib4/lean4 combos):

```
example {x : ℤ} (h1 : x + 4 = 2) : x = -2 := by linarith
```

I do not think mathlib4 has expository or tutorial documentation for the existing tactics, but it does have reference documentation here: https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/index.html

The Mathlib tab has a Tactics tab where you can discover the Linarith tactic as well as many other tactics for various theories, such as a ring solver.

Comment: Wonderful.  Thank you, Andrew.  Thanks for the pointer to the Tactics tab.